# How to combine python lists, with shared items, into new lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set, intersection

I am new to python and I hit a roadblock.  I have a python list that contains a single list on each line.  Basically, I would like to combine lists that share values among lists.  For example,
below is what my python list looks at the moment and what I would like the data to look like after the additional commands are executed.

I know this sort of problem is ideal for sets and intersections, but I just haven't been able to get them to work correctly.  I have also seen a post using indexes and that hasn't worked for me either.

What the list looks like:

```
[
    ['mary', 'home'],
    ['mary', 'school'],
    ['mary', 'work'],
    ['bob', 'home'],
    ['bob', 'school'],
    ['bob', 'work'],
    ['tom', 'work'],
    ['tom', 'school'],
    ['tom', 'home'],
    ['bill', 'vacation'],
]
```

What I want it to look like:

```
[
    ['mary', 'bob', 'tom', 'home', 'school', 'work'],
    ['bill', 'vacation'],
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example data suggests that order is important in your input data, which would complicate the situation. Assuming that it's actually just an example and order *isn't* important, sets are indeed an ideal way to solve the problem:

```
data = [
    ['mary', 'home'],
    ['mary', 'school'],
    ['mary', 'work'],
    ['bob', 'home'],
    ['bob', 'school'],
    ['bob', 'work'],
    ['tom', 'work'],
    ['tom', 'school'],
    ['tom', 'home'],
    ['bill', 'vacation'],
]

combined = []

for subset in [set(d) for d in data]:
    for candidate in combined:
        if not candidate.isdisjoint(subset):
            candidate.update(subset)
            break
    else:
        combined.append(subset)
```

This uses Python's [`for`-`else`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct, which not everyone is familiar with. `combined` will contain a list of sets, so you might want to convert them to lists depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks Zero, it worked great!  You were right, order is not important.